# Send data from server through HTML file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My goal is to send text `left` or `right` triggered from my html file to all clients connected to server (my nodejs server file). I tried many online solutions but i am not able to understand and some of them not working, because am not regular nodejs programmer.

I have created web app in html with two buttons `left` and `right`. When i click left button on html file my all connected clients should get text "left". I also created `server.js` nodejs file which is perfectly communicating with all clients. Problem is how can i get communication between html file and server file.

**Note :** `html` file is server side trigger point not `client`.

**server.js**

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 8888;

net.createServer(function (sock) {
console.log('connected : ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':'+sock.remotePort);
var ip = sock.remoteAddress.split(':')[3];
console.log(ip);
sock.write('hello client you are connected with server 10.0.0.19...');

sock.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('DATA '+ sock.remoteAddress+' - '+data);
    sock.write('you said : '+data);
});

function sendto(result) { //tried call from html file 
    console.log('sent '+result);
    sock.write('data : '+result);
}

sock.on('close', function (data) {
    console.log('closed');
});

}).listen(PORT);

console.log('server running on '+PORT);
```

Help me with way to communicate my `html file` with `server.js`, but not as `client`.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSE , server sent events to send a event from your server to all your connections.

From Client : 
Whenever you click the left/button you hit a api of your NODE. The same API when hit will publish a SSE to all the clients.

In the Subscriber End ,

```
var source = new EventSource("/pageTell"); (an API which your server exposes)

source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

Comment: I am confused with this `Subscriber End` means client side right, but client code is done by other programmer and in c#. Am not working client side, i need to send just string to him with socket programming. And that string will be "left" or "right" which will trigger from my html file.

Comment: Subscribers can be on both the sides. And yes the frontend developer/client side developer has to implement the subscribers/listeners to accept message.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP, by default, is a short lived request response connection which is not always connected. Meaning, the server sends out a HTML or related page, and then the connection is disconnected. Based on your use case you need the server to keep the connection open so that all connected clients can be informed of state changes.

For your usecase, you need something like WebSockets (very neatly documented on html5rocks https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). OR if you intend to support older browsers look at socket.io . Socket IO basic sample should be able to help you in achieving your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for this. It has node module as well as client side library.
Implement socket listener on all the clients. Whichever client is listening to the event will receive the data. Emit the data with event name when the button is clicked using the client side javascript of socket io. Check this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-socketio-and) out for the same.